# What is the sequencing between CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a weird intermittent bug that occurs after populating a list embedded in a swiper. Essentially I am getting an overflow of the last element of the list over a footer.

The strange things is that it appears some time after I have finished inserting the last node and in fact after I have called the swiper reninitialiser.

If I trigger a resize event it fixes itself - but only if I wait between 500ms to 2s after I have called the swiper reinit.

And to make it all very interesting the amount of the overlap varies all the time.

Which makes me wonder if what I am seeing is the javascript populating the list and calling the swiper reinit and then somewhere in the bowels of firefox and chrome all the styles are being applied which is causing the overflow.

I don't really want to use a timer related trigger - because of different user CPU speeds. and I don't want to use a keep trying it until it does - because sometimes it doesn't occur at all.

Anyway does anyone have the 60 second lecture of when CSS is applied in relation to javascript - and would there by chance be some event that tells me it is complete so I can check the divs after it has all been resized?

Comment: Got a sample? A link to the issue or a js fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no delay while CSS styles are applied via CSS stylesheets.  Styles are applied before a repaint or before a relayout.  There is no need to ever wait for CSS stylesheet rules to be applied unless you are loading a stylesheet dynamically or placing it after the HTML that it affects.

My guess is that something in the swiper reinitialzer is doing something before the changed content has been properly laid out.  The delay allows the layout to happen so the next time it's resized, it all fixes itself.

Without seeing what is really going on (probably in a working web page) and knowing more about the swiper code, all we can do is guess.  My wild guess would be that a layout has to happen after modifying the list and before a reinitialize.  There are several ways to force a layout by requesting certain properties that the browser knows are not accurate until a layout happens.  Waiting for a repaint with a `setTimeout(fn, 1)` will also trigger any pending layout before the `fn` callback is called and any time value in the `setTimeout()` will work because just waiting for the `setTimeout()` to fire lets the repaint happen.

You can see how to trigger a layout in [this article](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/) (request any of these properties `offsetTop, offsetLeft, offsetWidth, offsetHeight, scrollTop/Left/Width/Height, clientTop/Left/Width/Height`).